# Change MDCActivityIndicator track color in iOS

Tags: ios, material-design

I'm using MDCActivityIndicator for iOS.

I can see the track behind the indicator with ***trackEnabled = true***

But I don't know how to change the track color.

Do you know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I used MDCActivityIndicator as a cocoapods.

I pull out from cocoapods and add a source and fix it directly.

[MCDActivityIndocator](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios-codelabs/tree/master/MDC-111/Swift/Starter/Pods/MaterialComponents/components/ActivityIndicator/src)